# Can I fix screen size in ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm writing simple text game on Linux using c++ and ncurses library. My code for coloring and borders is:

```
start_color();
init_pair( 1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK );
box( gameWindow, ACS_VLINE, ACS_HLINE );
box( mainMenu, ACS_VLINE, ACS_HLINE );
```

The problem is that there is a small space around my game screen border that still has default terminal window color. It looks like ncurses is ignoring those not fully visible cells, but I need to cover them with color too. Is there any way to do that using ncurses?

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTwhN.png)

Comment: There is no such thing as "not fully visible cells". If your screen has a bezel, ncurses or any other terminal API cannot paint it.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the idea of screen. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Some terminals will color the window border to make it look consistent (the area outside the terminal-emulation), some will not.  ncurses has no control over the window border.